# Aspects on Webflux acting funky

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-webflux, reactive

I am developing code for both MVC and Webflux endpoints. I have written AspectJ code for Autologging, pretty standard.

But, whenever I apply this Autologging code for Webflux endpoints, there seems to be a memory leak and when I stop the server, it closes with a warning.

```
2018-11-21 17:49:25.456  INFO [webflux-async_logback,,,] 6174 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application shutdown requested.


WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/Users/ahallim/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.12/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Is writing Aspects for Webflux/Reactive code a bad idea? If yes, why? Is there anyway to address this and mitigate?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why does that warning indicate a memory leak? There is no such mention... Even without aspects this message occurs (at least it did with me). It has to do with tomcat doing some reflected calls that are deprecated in Java 10+.

Comment: I thought there could be memory leak as the system slowed down drastically. But, seeing your comment I couldn't reproduce the issue. Aspects on Webflux is running fine as of now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a memory leak. Webflux and AOP work together just fine.